# Newton's 2nd law and gravitational law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

I am studying the Newton's Law's of Motion, and really confused about one thing.

I know that bodies of very small mass get attracted to our earth due to a force it exerts, due to its huge mass.
So that, according to the Newton gravitational equation, a given small mass on earth will be attract by a certain force and depends on the distance of separation from earth's core.
Right now I am dropping a pen on a table and observing the sound. Higher the height from which I drop it more the sound it makes, showing that (I believe) more force is being exerted. Although from Gravitational equation of Newton, we can observe that the same force is being exerted on the pen because I am dropping the same pen from heights not so far away from each previous drop.

My question is that from second law of Newton, change in momentum causes force. But from gravitation law of Newton, the same force pulls the pen down. But the change in momentum is happening due to gravity, but the gravitational force is constant so that, the pulling force is constant, thus, why every different drop do I hear a different sound.

What is the right thing here?
I am really confused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The impact force of the pen is due to its change in momentum resulting from the impact and is independent of the force of gravity.

Of course the pen’s momentum just prior to impact is due to the work done by the gravity. For a height $h$ where the force of gravity is constant that work is $mgh$ and equals its kinetic energy just prior to impact, or

$$mgh=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

$$v=\sqrt{2gh}$$

The momentum just prior to impact is

$$p=mv$$

The average impact force is then the average change in momentum, or

$$F_{ave}= \frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}=m\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$$

If the object comes to a stop, $\Delta v=\sqrt{2gh}$ and

$$F_{ave}=m\frac{\sqrt{2gh}}{\Delta t}$$

The shorter the stopping time and/or the greater the height of the fall, the greater the average impact force.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1. Clear, concise and to the point.

Comment: Thank you I understood.

Answer (score 1):

We're dealing with two separate concepts here: gravitational force and kinetic energy. The gravitational force exerted on an object (like the pen) by Earth is indeed a constant, assuming the height difference isn't vast, i.e. the gravitational field is homogeneous (an example of a the opposite is [spaghettification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification)). This force can be given by Newton's law of gravitation:
$$
F = \frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}, \tag{1}
$$
where $G$ is the gravitational constant, $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the masses of the objects, and $r$ (as alluded to) is the distance between the objects center of masses.

In your example, we can consider the kinetic energy of the pen to be given be:
$$
K = \frac{1}{2}m_2v^2. \tag{2}
$$
Now lets consider Newtons $2^{nd}$ law:
$$
F = m a. \tag{3}$$
The gravitational force (weight) provides the object with an acceleration
$a$. Therefore, the longer the pen falls, the more time it has to accelerate due to the gravitational force, which means it gains more velocity and thus more kinetic energy. When it hits the table, the kinetic energy is partly transformed into sound energy.

Hence, the higher you drop the pen from, the more kinetic energy it will have when it hits the table, and the louder the sound will be.

Comment: I understand. So the gravitational force gives the ```a```,  and due to the ```a```,  the change in momentum of pen happens when it falls and thus more force. So we may, very simply, say that the force that a falling object imparts on the ground is a combined result of gravity and its fall?

Comment: You're generally on the right track. The force exerted on the table during impact relates to the change in momentum of the object. The greater the momentum of the object (due to falling from a greater height), the greater the change in momentum when it stops upon impact.

Comment: Ooooh, I understand, so initially if v = 0 and goes on to v = 50 say. When it hits a rigid floor, time for stopping approaches 0 and change in momentum is change in momentum during fall. Understood.         
                                                    Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The sound it makes when it hits the table depends on its speed when it hits.  The higher you drop it from, the more time it has to accelerate (with the acceleration of gravity) and the higher its speed when it hits.